# Print to Console on left click C#

Tags: c#, onclick

The code below shows mouse position in console every 500ms. I am trying to figure out How to only get mouse position to show when a left click happens. 
Example of what it does now below.

[image]

```
public static void MacroMouseThread()
{
    Console.WriteLine("MouseLocation Started");

    while (true)
    {
        // Shows mouse location cords 
        Console.WriteLine(Cursor.Position.ToString()); 
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

}
```

I want to left click anywhere on screen and it prints to console opposed to it it constantly printing continuously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event driven programming.

```
this.MouseClick += mouseClick;

private void mouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Mouse clicked");
        Console.WriteLine(Cursor.Position.ToString());
    }
}
```

I don't see your whole code, but you get the idea.

For further reading, please search Event Driven Programming in C# and Delegates.

A good tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008553/Event-Driven-Programing-in-NET

Comment: And how do you think this is going to work in a console app?

Comment: I didn't say run this code, I'm trying to say that event driven programming has to be used. I don't see his application in full either.

Comment: Your answer is completely nonsense in a console app though, there is no way to do this with pure event driven programming.

Comment: @DavidG I won't argue.

Comment: Thank you I found out what I have gotten so far from MSDN, But I could not figure out this particular situation. Thank you for the help. I will try and figure out how to implement it.

Comment: @Saibot You won't argue? Does that mean you are agreeing with me?

Comment: @OfficerDangle You are welcome.